# jquery append not working in IE with var declaration?

Tags: jquery

First of all here are a lot of discussion on stackoverflow about this question, however this one is quite different. I had the code 
in html it is `<table id="taxonomyUpload"></table>`

```
var rowM = $("<tr id=" + fileRowName + ">");
rowM.append($("<td bgcolor='#578ABA' height='10%' align='center'><x class='ez'>" + fileName 
+ ":</x></td><td><input type='file' id='" + fileName + "' name='" + fileName 
+ "' size='40' onchange='checkFiles(this);'/></td><td><div id=" + fileMinusDivName + " style='display='none''><img src='images/minus.jpg' height='20' onclick='deleteRow(" 
+ fileRowName + "," + index + ")'/></div></td><td><div id=" + filePlusDivName + " style='display='inline''>" 
+ "<img src='images/plus.jpg' height='20' onclick='moreFiles()'/></div></td></tr>"));
$("#taxonomyUpload").append(rowM);
```

this was working fine in firefox but not in IE. After many tries and reading few threads from stackoverflow I thought of not declaring any variable but to directly append the string. And my final code is

```
$("#taxonomyUpload").append($("<tr id=" + fileRowName + "><td bgcolor='#578ABA' height='10%' align='center'><x class='ez'>" + fileName 
+ ":</x></td><td><input type='file' id='" + fileName + "' name='" + fileName 
+ "' size='40' onchange='checkFiles(this);'/></td><td><div id=" + fileMinusDivName + " style='display='none''><img src='images/minus.jpg' height='20' onclick='deleteRow(" 
+ fileRowName + "," + index + ")'/></div></td><td><div id=" + filePlusDivName + " style='display='inline''>" 
+ "<img src='images/plus.jpg' height='20' onclick='moreFiles()'/></div></td></tr>"));
```

This way I could get the append code working for IE also. But I am stuck with a question that why did it happen? Is it that var is not supported in IE?

Comment: Not verry usefull but this happens because it's IE...

Comment: are you appending on dynamically-created nodes

Comment: @RTB: there should be some other reason.

Comment: No need to wrap the appended item in `$()` - just `$("#taxonomyUpload").append("<...>");`

Comment: @diEcho: As there above in code I have an html to specify the table. So not appending to dynamic node, atleast for first append.

Comment: @lnkbug: even after removing the $() wrap the issue remains the same as above in question statement.

Comment: styles and alignment of <div> also breaks down in IE. Seems like the statement made by @RTB is right.

Comment: the code containing var rowM declaration from the above question statement worked fine when I changed the code `$("#taxonomyUpload").append(rowM);`  to `$('#taxonomyUpload').append(rowM);` . Just used the single quote than the double quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the code running by replacing the double quote of `$("#taxonomyUpload")` to single quote `$('#taxonomyUpload')`; thus the working code was

`var rowM = $("<tr id=" + fileRowName + ">");
rowM.append($("<td bgcolor='#578ABA' height='10%' align='center'><x class='ez'>" + fileName 
+ ":</x></td><td><input type='file' id='" + fileName + "' name='" + fileName 
+ "' size='40' onchange='checkFiles(this);'/></td><td><div id=" + fileMinusDivName + " style='display='none''><img src='images/minus.jpg' height='20' onclick='deleteRow(" 
+ fileRowName + "," + index + ")'/></div></td><td><div id=" + filePlusDivName + " style='display='inline''>" 
+ "<img src='images/plus.jpg' height='20' onclick='moreFiles()'/></div></td></tr>"));
$('#taxonomyUpload').append(rowM);`

this is what could get me run append in IE also.

Comment: I found that, in jquery, it's preferable to use single quote than double quote in cases like above.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with append in IE to. I solved with changing `append()` to `appendTo()`.
So instead of `$(a).append(b);`, write `$(b).appendTo(a)`;

Hopes this works for you as it did for me :)

Comment: This also is situation for me like works in FF but not in IE-8.0

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are saying in the comment :/

Comment: Even if I use appendTo() than append() it gives me proper output on firefox but doesn't work fine with Internet Explorer.